# Where did the Facebook Notes settings go?

Tags: facebook, rss, blog

I used to configure Facebook to automatically pull from my blog and generate Notes, but I don't want anymore.

Unfortunately, the settings for this system seem to have changed, and I can't find the Notes' settings anymore. Any idea where it is?

Note: I was not using twitterfeed or any third-party application, but the Facebook-provided feature described [here](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/02/22/how-to-import-your-blog-into-facebook/).

Comment: I am noticing the evolution of your question thread over long-term shows how much a product can change if you pay attention. I am grateful Stack allows some questions to get older here. (Sometimes there is not this much patience for that kind of technical knowledge, as at each stage here your different answers show how programs can drastically alter & change if you just wait. You've a full profile of the product in better form than elsewhere even https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Facebook_features#Notes doesn't have the facts yet, you or I should edit the wiki, you want to do the honors?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**After 2020.10.31, "Facebook Notes" ([A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Facebook_features#Notes), [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Facebook#cite_note-MashableNotes-130)) is *being deprecated*** (programmer-speak for a "Deleted"/"Killed" feature basically) quietly/silently with nearly zero warning.[image: Screenshot from 2020-11-05 02-02-08 #Log.png using Google Chrome 81 Stable Build]*Their entire/only warning message, only shows at facebook.com/($user)/notes_drafts in 1-2 lines, is easy for anybody to miss.*

Their reason we have to guessvestigate (because there is not any official reason, it would seem random to the normal average user who relies on the Notes feature) is:

> "I haven’t discerned exactly why Facebook is discontinuing the feature
> other than it’s simply a little-used remnant of a failed strategy."
>
> "Facebook promised media outlets that publishing through something
> like Facebook Notes would result in new monetization opportunities and
> millions of new subscriptions. I didn’t see how that could happen and
> deep down, the publishers knew they were being scammed, too."
>
> —Mark Schaefer, COO of B Squared Media,, who was marketed the feature at a
> Columbia University meeting, https://businessesgrow.com/2020/10/14/facebook-notes (https://archive.today/Kmm4j, https://archive.today/kI2EX, https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://businessesgrow.com/2020/10/14/facebook-notes)

**Facebook did not give any substantial/tangible warning** other than the screenshot evidence given (we would be dreaming to expect megacorporations to give equal information for marketing blitzes as for wild deprecation retreats, there is not any User Law requiring informing users whose important profile data is trampled), so others finding after the fact that their drafts are gone who did not make https://www.facebook.com/dyi "Download Your Information" backup archives are going to be totally suprised, caught off guard, and deeply hurt users.

Answer (score 5):

You can type "Notes" into the search bar at the top when you're logged in. First result is ["Notes (App)"](http://www.facebook.com/notes.php) which you click through to.

On the left side of the Notes page, you'll see [Edit Import Settings](http://www.facebook.com/editnotes.php) as the last item.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

[This is no longer supported](http://www.facebook.com/help/206051139465982/).

> Importing a blog or RSS feed to your personal Facebook account is no longer available. If you want to share your blog posts on Facebook, you can:
>
> - Use Facebook Notes to customize your blog posts in a rich format that's compatible for readers on Facebook
> - Link directly to your blog posts from your status

Comment: +1 Indeed. Strange that they would drop this feature. I guess I will have to find a third-party app that does the same thing.