# Where did the Cryptowatch Footer/Notification Bar visibility setting go? Did the official setting disappear, to close the advert saying "Changelog"?

Tags: user-interface

Every time I try to make a financial decision while staring at the crypto tickers, I do not need to read "[Changelog](http://web.archive.org/web/20201208172653/https://docs.cryptowat.ch/home/updates/changelog#homepage-ftx-trading-uniswap-charts-trix): Nov 17, 2020: Homepage, FTX Trading, Uniswap Charts, TRIX" again in bright yellow with their greatly worded/timed ideas and their social media handle adverts repeated to me like I can/could not read it the first time. Genuinely a pain, I have been forced to think about it due to a sudden unlogged change, and it figures that there was not any time/thought given to writing any equal Changelog notification about this Settings change.

There used to be a Setting somewhere, maybe in the Hotkeys dialogue?

I used to configure [Cryptowat.ch](https://cryptowat.ch) (at https://cryptowat.ch/charts/COINBASE-PRO:CVC-USDC charts page) to show and hide the footer/bottom bar, which fortunately calmed my emotions/nerves at some times if it was triggering me.

Unfortunately, the settings for this/that system seem to have changed (still there's not any unified/consolidated interface for user interface settings *period*, so normally already very confusing to keep checking the disparate/separated official feature settings), and I can not find the bar visibility setting now. Any idea where it is?

Note: I am/was not using the API, nor Greasemoney script, nor any third-party application, just the Cryptowatch-provided feature described here.

<sup>*Inspired in part by (should I cite/mention their username? For Creative Commons license? I paraphrased their pain point wording, so I could ask so clearly, given the[ir] basic code is the same formula/question, and had allowed a good longitudinal study) how [Where did the Facebook Notes settings go?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13011/where-did-the-facebook-notes-settings-go) asked such an important question in clear code.*</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pro tip: use [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) to select and hide that element, or just paste the below code under the code tab:

```
#changelog-container {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Works! Wonderful. You might laugh if you knew how many times I tried using Google Chrome's "Inspect Element..." to find the CSS for Stylebot/Stylus, because Cryptowat.ch has SO MANY dynamic/encrypted/on-the-fly CSS variables (reminds me of Gmail/Workflowy's messy 'hidden' CSS techniques) which showed when I "moused-over" the Changelog area. (I literally gave up trying to find the exact CSS identifier, and you found the one named "Changelog" exactly, so now I feel embarassed I did not search that $word in the CSS first. Remarkable find; the cleartext ids/classes shld be in their Documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer: Click the "Fullscreen Icon" [(if you can find it, good luck; instructions will be here if you need help, it always looks different in different places I know who thought of this right I know)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52792453/unicode-character-to-represent-fullscreen)** (double arrows pointing at eachother diagonally), **between the words "Share" and "Auto".** Here is a picture [image: Fullscreen Icon from The Noun Project] from https://TheNounProject.com/term/fullscreen/26508/ but I bet you'll still end up staring looking for where it is and have to read me twice then realize it was there the entire time.

**Full answer: Only works if you go Full Screen (!)** (we're in 2021 now by the way, these are the standard bearers), so not if you keep Cryptowat.ch open in a tab for example. There is not any reason, just not any standards, the interface was just someone's feeling in "CSS", CSS was definitely not designed/taught first to help you track/read.

*I do not have an answer for why it is stuck there just questions, I mean it's like your local bank putting cereal box idea reminders, about how Cheerios improved again in Comic Sans kid print, on your deposit slips. This is the state of "price oracles" we are "regulating" by not using the actual programming lexicon with interface examples, to directly describe the issue(s) in a legal way.*